# Have the entire list of products inserted in the order form

Tags: php

I'm trying this simple order management software but I'm having difficulty fixing this thing:
I've to create order lists and print them.
The app automatically inserts one product at a time (with autocomplete function for search items and add row button) to create the order and then print a sort of invoice.
Instead I'm trying to have the entire list of products inserted (table "item_list" from sql), only to be completed with quantity and price if necessary.
I tried to recall the product list from the sql table but it doesn't update the descriptions automatically and it doesn't print the final report.
hope you understand what i mean
thanks in advance!

From this:
[image: before]

to this in automatic:
[image: after]

````
if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0){
  $qry = $conn->query("SELECT * from `po_list` where id = '{$_GET['id']}' ");
  if($qry->num_rows > 0){
      foreach($qry->fetch_assoc() as $k => $v){
          $$k=$v;
      }
  }
}
?>
<style>
  span.select2-selection.select2-selection--single {
      border-radius: 0;
      padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
      padding-top: 0.25rem;
      padding-right: 0.5rem;
      padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
      padding-left: 0.5rem;
      height: auto;
  }
  /* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
      input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
      input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      margin: 0;
      }

      /* Firefox */
      input[type=number] {
      -moz-appearance: textfield;
      }
      [name="tax_percentage"],[name="discount_percentage"]{
          width:5vw;
      }
</style>
<div class="card card-outline card-info">
  <div class="card-header">
      <h3 class="card-title"><?php echo isset($id) ? "Update Purchase Order Details": "New Purchase Order" ?> </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
      <form action="" id="po-form">
          <input type="hidden" name ="id" value="<?php echo isset($id) ? $id : '' ?>">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
              <label for="supplier_id">Supplier</label>
              <select name="supplier_id" id="supplier_id" class="custom-select custom-select-sm rounded-0 select2">
                      <option value="" disabled <?php echo !isset($supplier_id) ? "selected" :'' ?>></option>
                      <?php 
                          $supplier_qry = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `supplier_list` order by `name` asc");
                          while($row = $supplier_qry->fetch_assoc()):
                      ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" <?php echo isset($supplier_id) && $supplier_id == $row['id'] ? 'selected' : '' ?> <?php echo $row['status'] == 0? 'disabled' : '' ?>><?php echo $row['name'] ?></option>
                      <?php endwhile; ?>
                  </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                  <label for="po_no">PO # <span class="po_err_msg text-danger"></span></label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm rounded-0" id="po_no" name="po_no" value="<?php echo isset($po_no) ? $po_no : '' ?>">
                  <small><i>Leave this blank to Automatically Generate upon saving.</i></small>
              </div>
          </div>
          
          <tbody>
      
          </tbody>
      </table>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="item-list">
                      <colgroup>
                          <col width="5%">
                          <col width="5%">
                          <col width="10%">
                          <col width="20%">
                          <col width="30%">
                          <col width="15%">
                          <col width="15%">
                      </colgroup>
                      <thead>
                          <tr class="bg-navy disabled">
                              <th class="px-1 py-1 text-center"></th>
                              <th class="px-1 py-1 text-center">Qty</th>
                              <th class="px-1 py-1 text-center">Unit</th>
                              <th class="px-1 py-1 text-center">Item</th>
                              <th class="px-1 py-1 text-center">Description</th>
                              <th class="px-1 py-1 text-center">Price</th>
                              <th class="px-1 py-1 text-center">Total</th>
                          </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                          <?php 
                          if(isset($id)):
                          $order_items_qry = $conn->query("SELECT o.*,i.name, i.description FROM `order_items` o inner join item_list i on o.item_id = i.id where o.`po_id` = '$id' ");
                          echo $conn->error;
                          while($row = $order_items_qry->fetch_assoc()):
                          ?>
                          
                          
                          
                          <tr class="po-item" data-id="">
                              <td class="align-middle p-1 text-center">
                                  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger py-0" type="button" onclick="rem_item($(this))"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                              </td>
                              <td class="align-middle p-0 text-center">
                                  <input type="number" class="text-center w-100 border-0" step="any" name="qty[]" value="<?php echo $row['quantity'] ?>"/>
                              </td>
                              <td class="align-middle p-1">
                                  <input type="text" class="text-center w-100 border-0" name="unit[]" value="<?php echo $row['unit'] ?>"/>
                              </td>
                              <td class="align-middle p-1">
                                  <input type="hidden" name="item_id[]" value="<?php echo $row['item_id'] ?>">
                                  <input type="text" class="text-center w-100 border-0 item_id" value="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>" required/>
                              </td>
                              <td class="align-middle p-1 item-description"><?php echo $row['description'] ?></td>
                              <td class="align-middle p-1">
                                  <input type="number" step="any" class="text-right w-100 border-0" name="unit_price[]"  value="<?php echo ($row['unit_price']) ?>"/>
                              </td>
                              <td class="align-middle p-1 text-right total-price"><?php echo number_format($row['quantity'] * $row['unit_price']) ?></td>
                          </tr>
                          <?php endwhile;endif; ?>
                      </tbody>
                      <tfoot>
                          <tr class="bg-lightblue">
                              <tr>
                                  <th class="p-1 text-right" colspan="6"><span><button class="btn btn btn-sm btn-flat btn-primary py-0 mx-1" type="button" id="add_row">Add Row</button></span> Sub Total</th>
                                  <th class="p-1 text-right" id="sub_total">0</th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                  <th class="p-1 text-right" colspan="6">Discount (%)
                                  <input type="number" step="any" name="discount_percentage" class="border-light text-right" value="<?php echo isset($discount_percentage) ? $discount_percentage : 0 ?>">
                                  </th>
                                  <th class="p-1"><input type="text" class="w-100 border-0 text-right" readonly value="<?php echo isset($discount_amount) ? $discount_amount : 0 ?>" name="discount_amount"></th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                  <th class="p-1 text-right" colspan="6">Tax Inclusive (%)
                                  <input type="number" step="any" name="tax_percentage" class="border-light text-right" value="<?php echo isset($tax_percentage) ? $tax_percentage : 0 ?>">
                                  </th>
                                  <th class="p-1"><input type="text" class="w-100 border-0 text-right" readonly value="<?php echo isset($tax_amount) ? $tax_amount : 0 ?>" name="tax_amount"></th>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                  <th class="p-1 text-right" colspan="6">Total</th>
                                  <th class="p-1 text-right" id="total">0</th>
                              </tr>
                          </tr>
                      </tfoot>
                  </table>
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                          <label for="notes" class="control-label">Notes</label>
                          <textarea name="notes" id="notes" cols="10" rows="4" class="form-control rounded-0"><?php echo isset($notes) ? $notes : '' ?></textarea>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                          <label for="status" class="control-label">Status</label>
                          <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control form-control-sm rounded-0">
                              <option value="0" <?php echo isset($status) && $status == 0 ? 'selected': '' ?>>Pending</option>
                              <option value="1" <?php echo isset($status) && $status == 1 ? 'selected': '' ?>>Approved</option>
                              <option value="2" <?php echo isset($status) && $status == 2 ? 'selected': '' ?>>Denied</option>
                          </select>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </form>
  </div>



  <div class="card-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-flat btn-primary" form="po-form">Save</button>
      <a class="btn btn-flat btn-default" href="?page=purchase_orders">Cancel</a>
  </div>
</div>
<?php 
                  $sql="SELECT * from `item_list` order by (`id`) asc ";
                  $query=$conn->query($sql);
                  $iterate=0;
                  while($row=$query->fetch_array()){
                      ?>
<table class="d-none" id="item-clone">
  <tr class="po-item" data-id="">
      <td class="align-middle p-1 text-center">
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger py-0" type="button" onclick="rem_item($(this))"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
      </td>
      <td class="align-middle p-0 text-center">
          <input type="number" class="text-center w-100 border-0" step="any" name="qty[]"value="0"/>
      </td>
      
      <td class="align-middle p-1">
          <input type="text" class="text-center w-100 border-0" name="unit[]"value="pz"/>
      </td>
      <td class="align-middle p-1">
          <input type="hidden" name="item_id[]">
          <input type="text" class="text-center w-100 border-0 item_id" value="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>" required/>
      </td>
      <td class="align-middle p-1 item-description"></td>
      <td class="align-middle p-1">
          <input type="number" step="any" class="text-right w-100 border-0" name="unit_price[]" value="0"/>
      </td>
      <td class="align-middle p-1 text-right total-price">0</td>
      
  </tr>
</table>
<?php
                      $iterate++;
                  }
              ?>
<script>
  function rem_item(_this){
      _this.closest('tr').remove()
  }
  function calculate(){
      var _total = 0
      $('.po-item').each(function(){
          var qty = $(this).find("[name='qty[]']").val()
          var unit_price = $(this).find("[name='unit_price[]']").val()
          var row_total = 0;
          if(qty > 0 && unit_price > 0){
              row_total = parseFloat(qty) * parseFloat(unit_price)
          }
          $(this).find('.total-price').text(parseFloat(row_total).toLocaleString('en-US'))
      })
      $('.total-price').each(function(){
          var _price = $(this).text()
              _price = _price.replace(/\,/gi,'')
              _total += parseFloat(_price)
      })
      var discount_perc = 0
      if($('[name="discount_percentage"]').val() > 0){
          discount_perc = $('[name="discount_percentage"]').val()
      }
      var discount_amount = _total * (discount_perc/100);
      $('[name="discount_amount"]').val(parseFloat(discount_amount).toLocaleString("en-US"))
      var tax_perc = 0
      if($('[name="tax_percentage"]').val() > 0){
          tax_perc = $('[name="tax_percentage"]').val()
      }
      var tax_amount = _total * (tax_perc/100);
      $('[name="tax_amount"]').val(parseFloat(tax_amount).toLocaleString("en-US"))
      $('#sub_total').text(parseFloat(_total).toLocaleString("en-US"))
      $('#total').text(parseFloat(_total-discount_amount).toLocaleString("en-US"))
  }

  function _autocomplete(_item){
      _item.find('.item_id').autocomplete({
          source:function(request, response){
              $.ajax({
                  url:_base_url_+"classes/Master.php?f=search_items",
                  method:'POST',
                  data:{q:request.term},
                  dataType:'json',
                  error:err=>{
                      console.log(err)
                  },
                  success:function(resp){
                      response(resp)
                  }
              })
          },
          select:function(event,ui){
              console.log(ui)
              _item.find('input[name="item_id[]"]').val(ui.item.id)
              _item.find('.item-description').text(ui.item.description)
          }
      })
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#add_row').click(function(){
          var tr = $('#item-clone tr').clone()
          $('#item-list tbody').append(tr)
          _autocomplete(tr)
          tr.find('[name="qty[]"],[name="unit_price[]"]').on('input keypress',function(e){
              calculate()
          })
          $('#item-list tfoot').find('[name="discount_percentage"],[name="tax_percentage"]').on('input keypress',function(e){
              calculate()
          })
      })
      if($('#item-list .po-item').length > 0){
          $('#item-list .po-item').each(function(){
              var tr = $(this)
              _autocomplete(tr)
              tr.find('[name="qty[]"],[name="unit_price[]"]').on('input keypress',function(e){
                  calculate()
              })
              $('#item-list tfoot').find('[name="discount_percentage"],[name="tax_percentage"]').on('input keypress',function(e){
                  calculate()
              })
              tr.find('[name="qty[]"],[name="unit_price[]"]').trigger('keypress')
          })
      }else{
      $('#add_row').trigger('click')
      }
      $('.select2').select2({placeholder:"Please Select here",width:"relative"})
      $('#po-form').submit(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var _this = $(this)
          $('.err-msg').remove();
          $('[name="po_no"]').removeClass('border-danger')
          if($('#item-list .po-item').length <= 0){
              alert_toast(" Please add atleast 1 item on the list.",'warning')
              return false;
          }
          start_loader();
          $.ajax({
              url:_base_url_+"classes/Master.php?f=save_po",
              data: new FormData($(this)[0]),
              cache: false,
              contentType: false,
              processData: false,
              method: 'POST',
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'json',
              error:err=>{
                  console.log(err)
                  alert_toast("An error occured",'error');
                  end_loader();
              },
              success:function(resp){
                  if(typeof resp =='object' && resp.status == 'success'){
                      location.href = "./?page=purchase_orders/view_po&id="+resp.id;
                  }else if((resp.status == 'failed' || resp.status == 'po_failed') && !!resp.msg){
                      var el = $('<div>')
                          el.addClass("alert alert-danger err-msg").text(resp.msg)
                          _this.prepend(el)
                          el.show('slow')
                          $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");
                          end_loader()
                          if(resp.status == 'po_failed'){
                              $('[name="po_no"]').addClass('border-danger').focus()
                          }
                  }else{
                      alert_toast("An error occured",'error');
                      end_loader();
                      console.log(resp)
                  }
              }
          })
      })

      
  })
</script> ```
````